# In MWAA, how do you fire an ECS container task and use a PythonSensor to check status?

Tags: airflow, mwaa

I am new to Airflow and using Amazon's Managed Airflow.

I would like to be able to fire an ECS task in Fargate using ECSOperator and immediately start a PythonSensor that polls ECS for status and, upon success, fires an SNS message.

I am stuck on getting the ECS Task ARN from the ECSOperator. I gather that I have to enable the ECSOperator to push variables to XCOM with do_xcom_push and provide context to the PythonSensor, which should allow me to use the task_instance to get the task_arn from a dictionary.

But no matter what I try, I always find XCOM to be empty:
[image]

Code:

```
def check_task_completed(task_id, **kwargs):
    task_instance = kwargs['ti']
    if task_instance:
        xcom = task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids=task_id)
        print(f'XCOM: {xcom}')
        print(f'XCOM json: {json.dumps(xcom)}')
        if xcom:
            for key, value in xcom.items():
                print(f'XCOM[{key}]: {value}')
            task_arn = xcom.get('task_arn')
            print(f'Task ARN: {task_arn}')
    else:
        raise Exception(f'No task instance found for {task_id}')

    client=boto3.client('ecs')
    response=client.describe_tasks(
        cluster='integration-cluster',
        tasks=[task_arn]
    )
    if response['tasks'][0]['lastStatus'] == 'STOPPED' and response['tasks'][0]['containers'][0]['lastStatus'] == 'STOPPED':
        if response['tasks'][0]['containers'][0]['exitCode'] == 0:
            return True
        else:
            raise Exception(f'Task {task_arn} has finished with error: {response["tasks"][0]["stoppedReason"]}')
    else: 
        return False

def fail_sns(messagetext, fail_sns_arn, context):
    sns=boto3.client('sns')
    response=sns.publish(
                TopicArn=fail_sns_arn,   
                Message=messagetext,
                Subject=messagetext   
                )
    
DEFAULT_ARGS={
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False
}

DAG_ID=os.path.basename(__file__).replace('.py', '')
with DAG(
    tags=["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"],
    dag_id=DAG_ID,
    default_args=DEFAULT_ARGS,
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(hours=4),
    start_date=datetime(2023, 5, 4, 0 , 0), 
    schedule_interval='0 2 * * *' 
) as dag:

    success_sns_message='CLIENTNAME_SYSTEMNAME_SUCCESS'
    fail_sns_message='CLIENTNAME_SYSTEMNAME_FAIL'
    success_sns_arn='arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:000000000000:CLIENTNAME_SYSTEMNAME_SUCCESS'
    fail_sns_arn='arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:000000000000:CLIENTNAME_SYSTEMNAME_FAIL'

    run_ecs_task=ECSOperator(
        task_id="ecs_operator_task",
        dag=dag,
        cluster="cluster-name",
        task_definition="task-definition-name",
        launch_type="FARGATE",
        overrides={
            "containerOverrides": [
                {
                    "name": "SYSTEMNAME-integration",
                    "command": [
                        "CLIENTNAME"
                    ],
                },
            ],
        },
        network_configuration={
            "awsvpcConfiguration": {
                "subnets": ["subnet-00000000", "subnet-00000001"],
                "assignPublicIp": "ENABLED",
                "securityGroups": ["sg-00000000000000000"],
            }
        },
        awslogs_group="/ecs/SYSTEMNAME-integration-task-definition",
        awslogs_stream_prefix="ecs/SYSTEMNAME-integration",
        do_xcom_push=True
    )

    await_task_finish=PythonSensor(
        task_id="py_sensor_task",
        python_callable=check_task_completed,
        op_args = ['ecs_operator_task'],
        mode="reschedule",
        poke_interval=120,
        timeout=60*60*2, #2 hours
    )    

    sns_pass=SnsPublishOperator(
        task_id="sns_pass",
        target_arn=success_sns_arn,
        message=success_sns_message, 
        subject=success_sns_message,
        retries =1
    )

    run_ecs_task 
    await_task_finish >> sns_pass
```

The ECS Task finishes successfully, but the Sensor fails on first run as it is unable to get the task_arn

Airflow version: 2.2.2
apache-airflow-providers-amazon version: 2.4.0

I previously tried to use an ECSTaskStateSensor but I found it to be unavailable until later versions of apache-airflow-providers-amazon. I would like to exhaust my options to implement this fire-ECS-async then monitor with a PythonSensor pattern before having to get buy-in from my entire team to migrate to a later version of Airflow, which would require updating a lot of DAGs